kafka partition for data affinity
I have a use case where I will have multiple messages tied to one order. Each message for one order has to be processed sequentially. To make sure messages that are tied to one order are processed by the same consumer, I am planning to use the partitioning technique.
I have 4 partitions currently, and there are 4 consumers processing the messages. In general, we have anywhere from a few hundred to a few thousand orders every day, and each order ID is unique. I would like to use oderId as a partition key. So,
1.Is there any issue with using a new partition key every time we have a new order?
2.Does Kafka keep track of all these partition ids to determine which partition this message is going to?
